# How do I use multiprocessing and thread variable value sharing

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a Multiprocess pool running followed by a thread creation. The multiprocess pool uses multiprocessing manager dictionary in order to share dictionary between processes. That is, as each process is created it updates the dictionary with its process id as key and the value it is assigned to that process (i.e. the assets it needs to look after).

There are instances when a process might fail or be killed. When this happens I compare the current running system process numbers to that of the original dictionary. If any processes are missing then I start a new process it assigns its id to the shared dictionary and I remove the old process id from the dictionary.

The issue that I am having is that the dictionary doesn't seem to be updated in the thread. That is, if the thread was created after the processes were created, the dictionary is ok, it receives the completed dictionary. If a new process is created (from inside the Thread as a result of a process failing) then the dictionary is not updated (I update the dictionary inside the function that sets up the process)

So even though the dictionary is a multiprocess manager dictionary it is only shared between processes and not in the thread.

Has anyone ever encountered this or know of a solution for sharing the updated dictionary with the thread that is established after the pool creation?

Simplified code below:

```
mgr = multiprocessing.Manager()
process_dict = mgr.dict()

pool = Pool(processes=round(5))
for x in range(6):
   processes = pool.apply_async(activateMainProgram, args=(process_dict, asset1,))
   #here all the processes are created and they update the dictionary with their ID's

loggerthread = Thread(target=processactivecheck, args=(process_dict))
#thread is created to monitor if any process failed
loggerthread.daemon = True
loggerthread.start()
```

```
def processactivecheck(process_dict):
    from datetime import datetime
    duration = datetime.now() - currentpingyoualiveprocesses
    duration_in_s = duration.total_seconds()
    if duration_in_s >=  300: #run every 5 minutes
        currentpingyoualiveprocesses  = datetime.now()
        process_dict_list = [eval(i) for i in process_dict.keys()] #get the active process dictionary
        allPyIds = [p.pid for p in psutil.process_iter() if "python" in str(p.name)] #get all python processes running on system
        inactiveprocesses = [i for i in process_dict_list if i not in allPyIds] #identify processes that are not running

        log.info("Current Active Processes : " + str(allPyIds))
        log.info("Processes that are required : " + str(process_dict_list))
        if (len(inactiveprocesses) >0):
            log.info("Processes that are missing : " + str(inactiveprocesses))

        if (len(inactiveprocesses) >0):
            log.error("The following processes have stopped : " + str(inactiveprocesses) + ", restarting")
            for item in inactiveprocesses:
                #activating fallen process
                log.error("Process " + str(item) + " has stopped working, reactivating ")
                item = str(item)
                log.error("Reactivating for asset : " + str(process_dict[item][0]))
                processes = pool.apply_async(activateMainProgram, args=(process_dict, process_dict[item][0]))
                #here the new process is created (to replace the failed process) and is assigned the asset to work on
                process_camera_dict.pop(item, None)
                #here we remove the Old, now dead process from the list
                #ISSUE: The new created process updates the shared dictionary but this change is NOT visible in the Thread (The thread only sees the OLD, original dictionary).
                time.sleep(5)
            inactiveprocesses = []
```

Comment: At first glance: `[eval(i) for i in process_dict.keys()]` looks positively horrible. What's happening there?

Comment: I think you'll have a better time if the processes themselves don't update the dict, but you use `mp.Process` by hand.

Comment: [eval(i) for i in process_dict.keys()] is just to return a list of all the processes that added themselves to the dictionary. The processes I need to check if they are still active compared to all the active python processes in the system. If one of my processes is missing from the system, I know to start a new process and assign it the asset that the old failed process was working on.

Comment: You should never need to use `eval`, that's the horribleness here.

Comment: Your system is far from waterproof anyway – any other process could theoretically reuse the same PID as one of your child processes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're complicating things – instead, just use `multiprocessing.Process` and a loop...

```
import multiprocessing
import os
import random
import secrets
import sys
import time


def watch_asset(asset):
    print(os.getpid(), "watching", asset)
    while True:
        if random.random() < 0.1:
            print(os.getpid(), "gack! falling down dramatically oh no")
            sys.exit(42)
        time.sleep(0.1)


def main():
    assets = [secrets.token_hex(8) for i in range(5)]
    watchers = {}
    try:
        while True:
            for asset in assets:
                if asset not in watchers:
                    watchers[asset] = multiprocessing.Process(target=watch_asset, args=(asset,))
                    watchers[asset].start()
                    print("Started watcher", watchers[asset].pid, "for", asset)
                    continue
                if not watchers[asset].is_alive():
                    print("Watcher", watchers[asset].pid, "for", asset, "died, restarting soon")
                    watchers.pop(asset)
            time.sleep(1)
    finally:
        print("terminating watchers")
        for watcher in watchers.values():
            watcher.terminate()
        for watcher in watchers.values():
            watcher.join(timeout=5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This prints out e.g.

```
Started watcher 11066 for 6246bcbc0a8a26ea
Started watcher 11067 for 52b4d6e77982f178
Started watcher 11068 for ed0a9ffb49fc020c
Started watcher 11069 for 6ac711ec1d4042e3
Started watcher 11070 for 912a4f54e4a5f2d8
11066 watching 6246bcbc0a8a26ea
11067 watching 52b4d6e77982f178
11069 watching 6ac711ec1d4042e3
11068 watching ed0a9ffb49fc020c
11070 watching 912a4f54e4a5f2d8
11066 gack! falling down dramatically oh no
11070 gack! falling down dramatically oh no
Watcher 11066 for 6246bcbc0a8a26ea died, restarting soon
Watcher 11070 for 912a4f54e4a5f2d8 died, restarting soon
11068 gack! falling down dramatically oh no
11067 gack! falling down dramatically oh no
Started watcher 11077 for 6246bcbc0a8a26ea
Watcher 11067 for 52b4d6e77982f178 died, restarting soon
Watcher 11068 for ed0a9ffb49fc020c died, restarting soon
```